# Trying to update Eclipse ADT - v 20.0.0 or above from v 18.x

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-virtual-device

(I am using eclipse 3.7.1)

After manually downloading Jellybean API in tools/android (instead of via ADT in Eclipse), I am experiencing some odd behaviour in Eclipse.

The Android folder in Preferences is now no-longer-specifiable! 
Error: 
This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 20.0.0 or above.  Current version is 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762.  Please update ADT to the latest version.

I then tried Install New Software, to grab this latest version. That does not work, with the following errors being displayed:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.common,2.7.0.v20120127-1122
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore,2.7.0.v20120127-1122
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change,2.7.1.v20120127-1122
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi,2.7.0.v20120127-1122
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.edit,2.7.2.v20120130-0943
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks,1.2.102.v201201190400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core,1.4.201.v201201101553
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.validation,1.2.303.v201202090300
```

Eclipse can't handle Android anymore, and uninstalling the API isn't working..

Answer (score 1):

Your Eclipse installation is missing the [Eclipse Web Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) (which are used for the XML editing inside the ADT plugin). Installing them with older versions of Eclipse is described directly in the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/troubleshooting.html#installeclipsecomponents).

If those links are not sufficient for you, then please add your used Eclipse version to the question, as the link for installing the Web Tools depends on that version.

Comment: The problem with installing anything with the Install New Software feature is that I receive the same errors